# VS2019 Reference a foreign project and its packaged assemblies in .Net 5.0

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

To recap how .net framework references work: Assume I have a .net framework class project called ProjectFw which references a .dll called Grpc.dll. When I create a new Solution as a .net framework  console project called ProjectFwRef which adds a reference to ProjectFw.dll the build automatically brings the .dll Grpc.dll into the release folder of ProjectFwRef.

But .net 5.0 does not do that: Assume I have a .net 5.0 class project called ProjectNet which references a package called Grpc. When I create a new Solution as a .net 5.0 console project called ProjectNetRef which adds a reference to ProjectNet.dll the build DOES NOT automatically bring the Grpc.dll nor Grpc package into the release folder of ProjectNetRef.

This fundamental difference in how foreign .dlls are imported into a .net 5.0 project begs the question of the best way to deal with it. One obvious answer is to manually add the package Grpc to ProjectNetRef. Am I missing a better solution? What if I do not know the .dll's a foreign project references? Do I have to wait for the dreaded 'Cannot load file or assembly' error to find out what package I should have added?

Comment: Hundreds of questions about this.  Keep in mind that .NET5 is actually .NET Core.  So google ".net core copy dependencies" to find these posts back.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I always browse related questions but found nothing however your suggestion to use 'copy dependencies' yielded a gold mine. The most common answer was <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> but that is not relevant to foreign projects. The best answer, not unexpectedly, was to Publish the foreign project, stuff that in a local package source, then add that package to the local project. That is a more elegant solution than my suggestion to manually add the foreign packages to the local project.